# Non-existent circular reference and/or non-calculating formulas

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that has several array formulas (3 columns of 920 rows, all searching through ~70k rows of raw data for index/matching). Up until today the sheet worked fine, in the sense that I had to switch calculations to manual to make changes or suffer 3 minute number-crunching wait-times.

I was trying to copy just the values from the sheet to another one when Excel randomly popped up saying that I had a circular reference. I didn't change any of the formulas and it said that the reference is in B3 (first row of data). The formula in B3 is a simple

```
=CELL("prefix",A3)
```

so obviously the reference is not circular. I tried clearing the formula and the status bar said that the reference was circular. I look in Formulas -> Error Checking and Circular References is grayed out. I decide to delete the column because it wasn't necessary anymore. Then excel says that it's in a different cell (like W819). I clear the contents, even though it's not *actually* circular and drag the formula from the cell above it. Calculate the sheet and excel says there's a circular reference in V819 (similar formula just with different references, none of which are circular). Rinse and repeat with a new reference every time, but in vastly different columns/rows.

I gave up, figuring I'll just deal with erroneous warnings. However, now I have formulas that aren't calculating. Presumably because I have a circular reference and excel won't complete the calculations.

Any ideas on how to get Excel to realize that it's full of crap? Or at least to calculate everything else?

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the formula isn't circular. If `A3` contains a formula which references a range that includes `B3`, then you could very well have a circular formula.

Comment: The A column is all hard data, no references. Even if it was a reference, I'd assume that excel would consistently state that there's a circular reference in B3 instead of jumping all over.

Comment: If nothing else, this got me thinking about my formulas and if I should have so many. I determined that I could delete about half of my information because the intense formulas were unnecessary about half of the time. So at least there's that.

Comment: That's the thing, @pnuts. The cell formula was for a different sheet (the one I copied the data to from this pesky sheet). I happened to need it for some reason in the "master" sheet and at some point excel thought it was circular. Deleting it just made excel whine about another cell (almost in the exact opposite corner of the sheet) so I don't think it was your answer. I'm using Excel 2013 from the Professional Plus package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I'm still not sure what happened exactly so other people should totally answer too, but the issue has resolved.

It occurred to me that a lot of rows contained parts of a different class that does not need the array formulas. I was able to delete about 36% of the formulas and in the process of doing so got excel to quit whining about non-existent circular references.

I'm guessing that the extent of number crunching that I have Excel doing, something got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing, literally just now, and the alleged circular reference that it is talking about in my spreadsheet is completely not even referenced to any other cell but just a formula, so excel might have exceeded its number of formulas it can calculate at a time.